Wrap XML with SOAP envelop in Java spring
I want to change below XML object to get converted with SOAP envelop using Java.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getGeoCodesRequest>
    <Addrs>
        <City>DENVER</City>
        <Country>UNITED STATES</Country>
        <PostCd>80212</PostCd>
        <State>COLORADO</State>
    </Addrs>
</getGeoCodesRequest>

Expected output
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
   <soapenv:Body>
<getGeoCodesRequest>
   <addrs>
    <city>DENVER</city>
    <statePrv>COLORADO</statePrv>
    <postCd>80212</postCd>
    <cntry>UNITED STATES</cntry>
  </addrs>
</getGeoCodesRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Please note in expected output I do not want <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
I tried using below code snippet
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();

However, I don't know where to pass that XML object.

It might be worth indicating the library or framework your code is based on.

I am using in hcl commerce. It usages spring framework
